# Translate Boolean values in Analysis Services / Power BI

Tags: powerbi, ssas, translation, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

When using Analysis Services, you can add a `Translations` file to provide locale dependant object names.  At present this is working fine.

When I come to view the data however, boolean `True` or `False` values are always in English.

As you can see from the screenshot below, the Power BI interface and visualisations have picked up the French language setting and applied the appropriate object names, but the `True` and `False` remain (the exact same is seen when actually downloading the French version of Power BI desktop too):

[image]

As a boolean/logical value is simply a `bit` value and not a `string` of data or potentially ambiguous due to formatting (such as `dd/mm/yyyy` and `mm/dd/yyyy` dates), I would have thought `Vrai` and `Faux` would be used as it is when using Excel formulas.

This seems to be purely an issue with how the Vertipaq engine transmits its data.  If you add a new Measure to a Power BI dashboard running in the French language that always returns `False`, you get the same problem:

[image]

and even if you analyse the model within French Excel, you get the same problem:

[image]

Has anyone found a way around this that ideally doesn't rely on string representations of the boolean values?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a localization inconsistency that Microsoft needs to fix.

It doesn't seem terribly difficult to work around though. If you're only working with the boolean value inside of calculation, then the text representation isn't important since you don't see it. If you need to display it, then you can put it in a text wrapper so it shows how you want it to.

```
TextBoolean = IF ( [Boolean], "Vrai", "Faux" )
```

---

**Edit:** According to [Microsoft documentation of the `FORMAT` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/format-function-dax),

> All predefined formatting strings use the current user locale when formatting the result.

So I'd recommend trying this:

```
FORMAT ( [boolean], "True/False" )
```

Comment: Your workaround only works if the solution is being deployed to one locale, which sadly I am not attempting to do, hence my note to avoid manual string substitutions.

Comment: @iamdave Does the `FORMAT` function follow localization? Try `FORMAT([boolean], "True/False")`.

Comment: It appears not, neither explicitly in a `DAX` Measure per your suggestion or as the default `Data Format` property specified for Boolean columns within the Analysis Services Model definition.